# Transforming Roman numbers to correct Arabic numerals by transforming an XML file via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, transform, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml input:

```
<root>
    <calc>
        <roman>XLIV</roman>
    </calc>
    <calc>
        <roman>DCXI</roman>
    </calc>
</root>
```

I want to output the following:

```
<root>
    <calc>
        <roman>XLIV</roman>
        <arab>44</arab>
    </calc>
    <calc>
        <roman>DCXI</roman>
        <arab>611</arab>
    </calc>
</root>
```

**By writing a XSLT. So far I wrote this XSLT but what else needs to be done to output the right result?**

> ```
> <xsl:transform
>   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>   xmlns:num="http://whatever"
>   version="2.0">
>
>   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
>     encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
>
>
>   <!-- identity transform -->
>   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
>     <xsl:copy>
>       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
>     </xsl:copy>
>   </xsl:template>
>
>   <xsl:function name="num:roman" as="xs:string">
>     <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:integer"/>
>     <xsl:number value="$value" format="i"/>
>   </xsl:function>
>
> </xsl:transform>
> ```

**Extra rules for validating Roman numbers:**

Several rules apply for subtracting amounts from Roman numerals:

- Only subtract powers of ten (I, X, or C, but not V or L)

Ex: For 95, do NOT write VC (100 – 5). DO write XCV (XC + V or 90 + 5)

- Only subtract one number from another

Ex: For 13, do NOT write IIXV (15 – 1 - 1). 
DO write XIII (X + I + I + I or 10 + 3)

- Do not subtract a number from one that is more than 10 times greater (that is, you can subtract 1 from 10 [IX] but not 1 from 20—there is no such number as IXX.)

Ex: For 99, do NOT write IC (C – I or 100 - 1). 
DO write XCIX (XC + IX or 90 + 9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to more clear in function as see in **XSLT 2.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:num="http://whatever"
    version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs num">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
        encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>


    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="roman">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <arab><xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="matches(., '[^IVXLCDM]|II[^I]|IIII+|XXXX+|CCCC+|V[^I]|[^I]?I[VIX][IVXLCDM]|[^I]?I[^VIX]')">
                <xsl:comment>Your Message about Not Roman Data</xsl:comment>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="num:roman(., 0)"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        </arab>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="num:roman" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:param name="r" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:param name="s"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($r,'CM')">
                <xsl:sequence select="900 + num:roman(substring($r,1,string-length($r)-2), 900)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($r,'M')">
                <xsl:sequence select="1000+ num:roman(substring($r,1,string-length($r)-1), 1000)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($r,'CD')">
                <xsl:sequence select="400+ num:roman(substring($r,1,string-length($r)-2), 400)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($r,'D')">
                <xsl:sequence select="500+ num:roman(substring($r,1,string-length($r)-1), 500)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($r,'XC')">
                <xsl:sequence select="90+ num:roman(substring($r,1,string-length($r)-2), 90)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($r,'C')">
                <xsl:sequence select="(if(100 ge number($s)) then 100 else -100)+ num:roman(substring($r,1,string-length($r)-1), 100)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($r,'XL')">
                <xsl:sequence select="40+ num:roman(substring($r,1,string-length($r)-2), 40)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($r,'L')">
                <xsl:sequence select="50+ num:roman(substring($r,1,string-length($r)-1), 50)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($r,'IX')">
                <xsl:sequence select="9+ num:roman(substring($r,1,string-length($r)-2), 9)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($r,'X')">
                <xsl:sequence select="(if(10 ge number($s)) then 10 else -10) + num:roman(substring($r,1,string-length($r)-1), 10)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($r,'IV')">
                <xsl:sequence select="4+ num:roman(substring($r,1,string-length($r)-2), 4)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($r,'V')">
                <xsl:sequence select="5+ num:roman(substring($r,1,string-length($r)-1), 5)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with($r,'I')">
                <xsl:sequence select="(if(1 ge number($s)) then 1 else -1)+ num:roman(substring($r,1,string-length($r)-1), 1)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:sequence select="0"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thank you. Just a modification in your XSL: How can I detect invalid Roman numbers and write a log message?

Comment: for invalid numbers you have to add a condition before calling function

Comment: And how would that look like in the above xslt? it would be a xsl:if if I am not mistaken?

Comment: But how would I do that in the code? I have no idea...could you please help with some of the conditions and how it would look in the code?

Comment: Compare: https://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200412/msg01063.html

Comment: @Rupesh I edit the answer by putting more validation on the roman numbers. I could not add one validation that I need help if you could please do it and update the answer (thanks in advance). I added the validation in the question. (Basically Greater values should not follow lesser values for ex: VC)

Comment: @Rupesh Could you please update your answer? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @Rupesh There is one case where the validation fails that I could find after testing. XIII (its a valid roman number and should output 13) but it invalidates it. As matter of a fact it invalidates III(valid roman number for 3) invalidates as well. I tried to fix it but wasn't successful, so could you please once more update the answer?

Comment: @hamedabedini change "|[^I]?I[VIX][IVXLCDM]|" with "|[^I]?I[VX][IVXLCDM]|".

Comment: @Rupesh Could you please look at this question when you get a chance? Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345058/transforming-numbers-to-roman-numbers-by-transforming-an-xml-file-via-xslt