# Transforming numbers to Roman numbers by transforming an XML file via XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml input:

```
<root>
    <calc>
        <arab>42</arab>
    </calc>
    <calc>
        <arab>137</arab>
    </calc>
</root>
```

I want to output the following:

```
<root>
    <calc>
        <roman>XLII</roman>
        <arab>42</arab>
    </calc>
    <calc>
        <roman>CXXXVII</roman>
        <arab>137</arab>
    </calc>
</root>
```

**By writing a XSLT. So far I wrote this XSLT but what else needs to be done to output the right output?**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>     <xsl:transform
>       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>       xmlns:num="http://whatever"
>       version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs num">
>
>       <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
>         encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
>
>
>       <!-- identity transform -->
>       <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
>         <xsl:copy>
>           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
>         </xsl:copy>
>       </xsl:template>
>
>     </xsl:transform>
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="calc">
    <xsl:copy>
        <roman>
            <xsl:number value="arab" format="I"/>
        </roman>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

> numbers should be between 1 and 3999.

To validate that the numbers are in the range of 1 to 3999, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="calc">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="1 le number(arab) and number(arab) le 3999">
                <roman>
                    <xsl:number value="arab" format="I"/>
                </roman>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:message terminate="no">Please enter a number between 1 and 3999</xsl:message>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Note that Saxon at least supports roman numerals up to 9999:
http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRKe

Comment: You probably want to include an `<xsl:copy>..` round the output, but why insist on XSLT 1 or 2? This solution works with either.

Comment: @Flynn1179 Thanks for the catch.--  As for the version, I asked so that I would know where to look for an answer. As it happens, the answer also works in XSLT 1.0, but that's not always the case.

Comment: How can I add some validation? When inputting number 0 should be an error and also the XSLT can handle numbers up to 3xxx. So the highest required letter from the Roman numbers will be ‘M’. So for instance any number higher than 3999 should be invalidated. So in short numbers should be between 1 and 3999.

Comment: What would be the expected result when the input does not pass this validation?

Comment: @michael.hor257k To have a text output message "Please enter a number between 1 and 3999"